# Bluetooth enable not working on android 12 React native

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-manager

According to android api leavel 31 I have updated code. before I am trying to enable bluetooth using `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`. for android 12 I have tried with multiple request like this `const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([ PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT]);`.

I am getting error on only on android 12

**Error is :**
[image]

**Code :**

#### Old code that not compatible with android 12

[image]

**Old AndroidManifest.xml**
[image]

**Android/build.gradle**
[image]

Versions :
[image]

#### After I updating this code for android 12 I got Permission is null Error

[image]
**Updated AndroidManifest.xml**

[image]
[image]

please let me know what I am missing, what i need to update or upgrade

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)